# BLE Health Thermometer Characteristic 2A1C Notification value decoding - React Native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I m using a BLE simulator app that simulates BLE Digital Thermometer standards - connected to my React Native App running on another device. I subscribe to notifications for the temperature measurement characteristic. After I get a notification after the set interval, the received_data.value is in the form byteArray example: [0, 0, 0, 12, 132] - for temperature reading of 35.

I m not sure how to transfer the byteArray [0, 0, 0, 12, 132] into 35 on my react native app? Any ideas on how to use JS/React-Native to solve this and temperature reading.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-string][convert-string] is what you're looking

```
import { bytesToString } from 'convert-string';
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
    'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic',
    ({ value, peripheral, characteristic, service }) => {
        // Convert bytes array to string
        const data = bytesToString(value);
        console.log(`Recieved ${data} for characteristic ${characteristic}`);
    }
  );
```

Comment: I tried that already. When I convert the bytes array to string using `bytesToString` function, the result I get is two unknown characters in the form of who boxes. shown in this [link](https://pasteboard.co/Jaza3QD.png)

Comment: I also tried to with `UTF8.bytesToString` which gave me an error - URIError: URI malformed. [View Error ScreenShot](https://pasteboard.co/JazczwQ.jpg)